# Using reinterpret_cast while respecting the strict aliasing rule

Tags: c++

I know this code would cause `undefined behaviour` due to breaking the strict aliasing rule,
as we are point to the same memory location with a type `int` and `float` and dereferencing it, code could break after compiler optimizations take place:

```
int main(){
 int a = 5;
 float f = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&a);

 return (int) f;
}
```

But how about this snippet?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
 intptr_t p = 1234; // let's assume this is a valid address in memory.
 float f = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(p);

 return (int) f;
}
```

In the above, if we assume `p` is a valid memory address (will not cause a segfault) will it still have UB and break the strict aliasing rule? there is no other code pointing to that chunk of memory.

#### Edit

My second example can be written like this using `bit_cast`:

```
intptr_t p = 1234; // let's assume this is a valid address in memory.
float f = *std::bit_cast<float*>(p);
```

Comment: You could make it `float orig; intptr_t p = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&orig); float f = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(p);` and it would still be UB since it's not initialized when you read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will still break the strict aliasing rule, as you will be trying to dereference a pointer to `float`, but `float` object never lived at this address.

Luckily, in C++ 20 you can use `std::bit_cast` for this purpose. Pre-C++20 you can just cast :), as even though this is UB, there is no sane compiler which would produce the results which would be different from the ones you are expecting, since this technique is omni-present everywhere.

Comment: But my `reinterpret_cast` is literally a bit cast (without using bit_cast itself of course), I guess the only difference is C++20 knows not to mess `bit_cast` up with optimization.

Comment: so this method is still widely used while it is known to be UB? I guess the output is correct most of the time.

Comment: @Dan: Normally, a float _does_ live at the address, making it not UB

Comment: @Dan, yep. `bit_cast` just tells compiler that the value can be aliased.

Comment: @Dan yes, in many real systems I worked with objects are aliased all the time for efficiency purposes. Usually it is not `int` to `float`, though, but rather blobs of data to `struct`s.

Comment: @SergeyA using `std::bit_cast` or the `reinterpret_cast` method i'm doing above?

Comment: @Dan pre-20 it was `reinterpret_cast` (or, often, two `static_cast`s via `void*` to adhere to the rule *no reinterpret_cast*), I expect people start using `bit_cast` now.

Comment: I see so even though it's UB, people just don't care as the chances of it breaking would be minimal?

Comment: @Dan people are often satisfied with practical results. If several nanos of performance can be eked out by using widely supported, although non-standard feature, it will be done. Please note, compilers often have switches to prevent it from any aliasing-related optimizations.

Comment: The thing with UB is you do it when A) you have no choice and B) you know exactly what the behaviour (through experimentation or years of experience) will be with the given compiler, OS, and hardware.

Comment: @user4581301 well said.

Comment: @Dan If you are really worried about UB, you can use the possible implementation from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) to implement `bit_cast` for yourself so you too can be UB free ;)

Comment: makes sense. and yes, I guess the only safe way (which `bit_cast` uses behind the scene) is using `memcpy` and copy the blob instead of pointing to it.

Comment: @NathanOliver that would defeat the purpose :), as it would perform memcpy.

Comment: @Dan, notably, real `bit_cast` DOES NOT `memcpy`, otherwise, people would not need it.

Comment: @SergeyA I see thanks for the clarification, so prior to `bit_cast` it was either memcpy, or just trust the reinterpret_cast and it's possible UB.

Comment: There was also a brief period where `std::launder` was standard and `bit_cast` wasn't.  I think you could use `std::launder` on a pointer which cannot be dereferenced without breaking strict aliasing to get a pointer which can.

Comment: @SergeyA> most compilers optimize away the memcpy on many types, making that approach both correct, and efficient and totally negating any value in using reinterpret_cast, barring doing it out of old habits. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/xdf1YG6ds)

Comment: @spectras we experimented. In particular, at time of experiment, icc was not replacing `memcpy` with aliasing. Also, it is much easier to confirm correctness than performance in, say, regression test suite exercised at compiler upgrade. Overall, we did not have the luxury to rely on `memcpy` optimization. (beside the fact that on some code paths it was not happening at all).

Comment: For sure, yet compilers move forward and tests done in the past should not guide a decision forever. Especially as correctness is not that easy to prove. In front of UB, broken code can pass tests, sometimes in very surprising ways. And in *most* contexts I'd rather have my code unexpectedly run slower rather than unexpectedly corrupt some of my data. Counterexamples definitely exist, but I'd argue correctness should be the default choice and UB the very last resort.

Comment: @SergeyA I just wanted to confirm with you that, my added `Edit` above is correct? i.e we can't do `std::bit_cast<float>(p);`, `p` is not a pointer itself, it's a regular value which holds a pointer, therefore we have to cast it  a `float*` first.